# How would I add a method to ActiveView::Helpers::FormHelper to be used with form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently making a plugin, and I would like to add a method to ActiveView::Helpers::FormHelper, Essentially, the plugin is a helper that will convert checkbox input into bitwise flags so when you do actions like new and update, you can continue to pass in a params hash, and my plugin will pull out the checkbox data and convert it into a single number representing the flag state. Anyway, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
<% form_for @person do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_boxes_for_flags %>
<% end %>
```

Which would create checkboxes in the HTML and then set them accordingly to the flags. I know how to add an instance method to ActiveView::Helpers::FormHelper, but I'm not sure how to access @person from this method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't you use:

```
<%= f.check_boxes_for_flags :country %>
```

That way you can create your extension similar to how the ActiveView helpers work.

Take a look at how [check_box_tag in the rails source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6a9e188c0c925634749478eb7cde43aead9b133f/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L292) gets the *name* from the model. Try to follow the conventions set forth by the framework, it makes things easier for you and those who will maintain your code after you.